# Required dependencies using Quarkus and Apache Camel with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, apache-camel, quarkus

I was trying to use Apache Camel with Quarkus. These are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-http")
    implementation("org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-rest")
    implementation("org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-core")
    implementation("org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-direct")
    implementation("org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-caffeine")
    implementation("org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-jackson")
}
```

But it seems this is not enough to use Camel, as the RouterBuilder class is not available.

[image]

These are the logs from running `quarkusDev`

```
   > Could not find org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-jackson:.
     Required by:
         project :applications:demo
   > Could not find org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-http:.
     Required by:
         project :applications:demo
   > Could not find org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-rest:.
     Required by:
         project :applications:demo
   > Could not find org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-core:.
     Required by:
         project :applications:demo
   > Could not find org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-direct:.
     Required by:
         project :applications:demo
   > Could not find org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-caffeine:.
     Required by:
         project :applications:demo
   > Could not find org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-caffeine-lrucache:.
     Required by:
         project :applications:demo

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

**Is it required to add the actual Camel dependencies in addition for all the Quarkus Camel dependencies I like to use?**

Comment: "*Is it required to add the actual Camel dependencies in addition for all the Quarkus Camel dependencies I like to use?*" - No, it is not. It should be pulled in transitively by the corresponding `camel-quarkus`-dependency (I think the `RouteBuilder` should be in `camel-quarkus-core`). Is this "just" IntelliJ complaining, or does the code not compile?

Comment: @Turing85 no the application does not build and complains about missing dependencies. I've edited the original post and added the logs

Comment: Looks like the dependency resolution does not work. Have you boostrapped the application via [`code.quarkus.io`](https://code.quarkus.io)?

Comment: No, I've just dropped in the Camel dependencies and I'm currently using the latest version 2.13.3. But I try to generate a sample project and look for differences

Comment: I am pretty sure that something in the bom setup isn't right. I highly recommend to always start with a bootstrap from `code.quarkus.io`, and abstract from there.

Comment: Yeah, it seems I do not have the camel bom in place `implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:quarkus-camel-bom:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")`